# Leaflet: Edit button not enabled when drawing over an ImageLayer

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.draw

All:
Perhaps I am not doing this the correct way.  The way Leaflet draw works is that as soon as you draw something on a map using the draw control (circle, square, polygon, whatever) the delete/edit button becomes enabled.  In my map, with clicks of links on my web page that contains the Leaflet map, a user can add many imageOverlays, but lets just say for this scenario the user clicked and added one imageOverlay. The imageOverlay appears fine on the map.  Now the user wants to draw a shape - say a circle - on the map.  When the user clicks on the circle icon in the draw control and paints it on the map the delete/edit button does NOT become enabled. I am stumped.  I suspect that this may have something to do with layers /layering.  I need to have that delete/edit button behave as it would if there were no imageLayers on the map. Can somebody please enlighten me?  Thank you.

My React.js code adds the imageLayers to array and the array of images is then added to a L.featureGroup.
When drawing a shape, the layertype is added to the same L.featureGroup.

My code:

```
In React.js:

let myFeatureGroup = new L.FeatureGroup();
let imageLayersArray = [];

// My function to load imageLayers:
const applyLayer = (mapSubType) => {        

    const mapSubTypeCaps = mapSubType.toUpperCase();

    let dlaBounds = null;

    const someOptions = {
        opacity: 0.3,
        interactive: true,
        bubblingMouseEvents: true,
        className: 'imageborder',
        zIndex: 5,
        mapsubtypelayer: mapSubType, // required in order to identify a layer upon removal
    };

    // The 8 PNG image coordinates:
    const ImageCoords = [
        [[-90, 0], [0, 90]],
        [[0, 0], [90, 90]],
        [[-90, -90], [0, 0]],
        [[0, -90], [90, 0]],
        [[-180, 0], [-90, 90]],
        [[90, 0], [180, 90]],
        [[-180, -90], [-90, 0]],
        [[90, -90], [180, 0]],
    ];

    let counter = 0;

    ImageCoords.map((coordEntry) => {
        counter++;
        const useThisURL = `https://dla-maps-storage.s3.amazonaws.com/DLAMAP${mapSubTypeCaps}${counter}.png`;

        // Need to flip the coordinates from lng/lat to lat/lng for leaflet:

        let arrayofcoordinates = [];
        const flippedarrayofcoordinates = [];
        arrayofcoordinates = coordEntry;

        arrayofcoordinates.map((pairofcoordinates) => {
            const workAry = [];
            // flip the coordinates from lng/lat config to lat/lng:
            workAry[0] = pairofcoordinates[1];
            workAry[1] = pairofcoordinates[0];
            flippedarrayofcoordinates.push(workAry);
        });

        dlaBounds = L.latLngBounds(flippedarrayofcoordinates);

        const anImage = L.imageOverlay(
            useThisURL,
            dlaBounds,
            someOptions,
        )

        // add the imagelayer to the imageLayersArray:
        // Somebody along the way recommended to do this
        imageLayersArray.push(anImage);

        anImage.on('click', (leafletEvent) => {
            handleImageClick(leafletEvent);
        });
    });

    myFeatureGroup = L.featureGroup(imageLayersArray).addTo(map);

};
    
// Draw Event Created:
map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, (e) => {
    console.log('L.Draw.Event.CREATED start:: ');

    const { layer } = e;

    switch (e.layerType) { // types: polyline, polygon, rectangle
        case 'circle':
            // Call rest endpoint with lat/lng coordinates
            break;
        case 'marker':
            // Call rest endpoint with lat/lng coordinates
            break;
        case 'polyline':
            // Call rest endpoint with lat/lng coordinates
        break;
        default:
            // POLYGON OR RECTANGLE DRAWN:
            // Call rest endpoint with lat/lng coordinates
        break;                  
}

    myFeatureGroup.addLayer(layer);

    console.log('L.Draw.Event.CREATED end:: ');
});
```

Comment: Please post your code so we can take a look, or use jsfiddle.net

Comment: Posted my code.  Thank you for your assistance.